# How to ensure space between labels MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am creating a line chart using MPAndroidChart, all is working great, but I've noticed that at the labels often become bunched up. I know there is a way to prevent this (I've seen other apps that don't have this issue,) but I don't know what setting to enable.

[image: a line chart with crowded labels]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could make the labels fit better.

1. Decrease the text size of the X axis labels with `mChart.getXAxis().setTextSize(float)`
2. Set a label count limit for the X axis using `mChart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(int)`. This should work fine, as you are already not showing one label per data point.
3. Change the date format of your label.

Some, all or none of these might help you, depending on your requirements. Good luck!